# Ist there a way to run JUnit 4 tests with Spring AspectJ LTW without using a jvm agent?

Tags: eclipse, spring, junit, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have a spring tomcat project configured with aspectJ LTW, I would like to run unit tests with AspectJ LTW. According to the spring docs running with LTW for a standalone JVM requires passing in arguments for a JVM agent.

Passing a JVM agent to junit tests is easy to do from ant, but very inconvenient to do when running a unit test in eclipse. Is there any way to configure the JUnit classes, so that LTW is turned on without using an agent?

For tomcat spring uses a transforming class loader to load run AspectJ LTW, is there something similar for JUnit, maybe a JUnit runner that does LTW?

**update:** By telling eclipse to store the .launch files in the eclipse project I am able to right click on unit tests and do Run As and it works because eclipse uses the .launch files, this is a workaround that I would like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would install the [AspectJ Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/), that way you get your aspects woven right in your Eclipse IDE. That way you don't need any special launcher.

Since you are using Spring, think about using the [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts). It's an Eclipse distribution that includes Spring tools and the AspectJ Development Tools.

Comment: I am using STS and I do have AJDT installed but I am not sold on compile time weaving so far.